# Angular app not running on Safari browser on desktop

Tags: angularjs, safari, gruntjs, jhipster

I have created an angularjs website with [generator-jhipster](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster). It is working nicely in all browsers except safari (on desktop). It is working even in iPhone but the website is not able to open in Safari on desktop.

After inspecting I can find following error:

```
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module movementsJhipsterOauth2App due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'movementsJhipsterOauth2App' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

**EDIT**

Version: generator-jhipster 2.18.0

Angular Version: Angular 1.4.8

Browsers: Safari 7.1

OS: MacOS

I am not getting what the error is all about as it is opening in other browsers without any error. Please suggest some solution.

Comment: @gaël-marziou please see my edit.

Comment: Wow JH 2.18.0 is super old, only suggestion I have is to generate an angularjs app using JH 4.7.0 and see if it has the same problem and then compare code and build configuration between both versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was obtained by hit and try i.e. by checking each controller, their dependency and its order in gruntFile.js and I found that there was a state which had params defined two times.
like:

```
.state('state1', {
        url: '/url',
        params:{
            'data1' : {}
        },,
        params:{
            'data2' : {}
        },
        views: {
            'content@': {
                templateUrl: 'xxx',
                controller: 'xxx'
            }
        },
        resolve: {
        }
    })
```

so adding data2 in first block and removing second one solved my issue from Safari.

Comment: Sorry that you spent time on this because tools can spot it within seconds.
Running `grunt eslint` first detects `Unexpected token ,`. Fixing it and re-running again detects the redefined params property: `Parsing error: Redefinition of property`.